# Updating multiple columns in a single sql query with conditions

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I need help in building a sql query for the following criteria:

there are 3 columns in oracle database, and i need to update one of these columns checking if 1st is null then update that and don't touch other two columns, if 1st is not null then update 2nd and don't update the 3rd column else if 3rd column is null update the 3rd.

The query which i could build is:

```
 update temp set 
    flg1 = 
        case flg1
            when null then 'Y' else flg1 end,
    flg2 = 
        case flg2
            when null then 'Y' else flg2 end,
    flg3 = 
        case flg3
        when null then 'Y' else flg3 end,
where id = 132
```

i know the above query is different from what i want , need help ..

Comment: what error r u receiving

Comment: it's not the error, the query is not correct, i need help in building the query.

Comment: if flag1 and flag2 is not null then flag3 will update?

Comment: if i run the query, and if all 3 fields are null then all will get updated to 'Y', This is something i don't want , i need only one column to be updated either 1st or 2nd or 3rd.

Comment: @Sachu yes the if 1st and 2nd is not null then 3rd should be updated ,and if all are not null then it should not update anything

Comment: @Tausifmohammad hope my answer help..let me know

Comment: @Sachu yes this is what is wanted , thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 update temp set 
        flg1 = 
            case when flag1 is null then 'Y' else flg1 end,
        flg2 = 
           case when flag1 is not null and flag2 is null then 'Y' else flg2 end,
        flg3 = 
            case when flag1 is not null and flag2 is not null and flag3 is null then 'Y' else flg3 end
where id = 132
```

Comment: Yes, this is what i wanted , Thanks Muazzam :)

Answer (score 0):

you should use neste case condition to achieve your requirement
Just try below code

```
update temp set 
            flg1 = 
                case when flag1 is null then 'Y' else flg1 end,
            flg2 = 
               case when flag1 is not null 
                   then case flag2 is null then 'Y' else flg2 end
               end,
            flg3 = 
                case when flag1 is not null 
                then case  flag2 is not null 
                then case flag3 is null then 'Y' 
                else flg3 end
                end 
                end
    where id = 132
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this?

```
UPDATE temp SET
    flg1 = 
        CASE WHEN flg1 IS NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE flg1 END,
    flg2 = 
        CASE WHEN flg1 IS NOT NULL AND flg2 IS NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE flg2 END,
    flg3 = 
        CASE WHEN flg1 IS NOT NULL AND flg2 IS NOT NULL AND flg3 IS NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE flg3 END

WHERE id = 132
```